# find group ID's within an svg file using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I have an svg file. In the file are a number of groups(see 'example SVG file'), I don't know how many first level groups are in the file.
Using fabricjs how can I find out the number of groups within the svg file like the result (see 'Result I'm looking for')?

Example SVG file:

```
<g id="group1">
    <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" fill="#00FF00" width="10" height="10"/>
    <rect id="rect2" x="10" y="10" fill="#FF0000" width="10" height="10"/>
    <rect id="rect3" x="20" y="20" fill="#0000FF" width="10" height="10"/>
</g>
```

**Result I'm looking for:**

```
#found 3 group ID's:
group1
group2
group3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Fabric, but I assume you can just use javascript if necessary like follows...

```
var svg = document.getElementById("mainsvg");

var groupCount = 0;
var childNodes = svg.childNodes;
var childNumber = childNodes.length;

for( a=0; a<childNumber; a++ ) {

    if( childNodes[ a ].localName == 'g' ) {
        console.log( childNodes[a].attributes.id.value );
        groupCount++; 
    }
}

console.log( groupCount );
```

There's a fiddle here.. http://jsfiddle.net/5RyZK/3/ (You may want to check if it has an id first and push it to an array or something.